# Hibernate - could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm using spring-mvc and hibernate session-factory.

```
@Controller
    |
    ->  @Service (@Transactional)
            |
            -> @Repository
```

I have 2 entities, `User` and `Address`.

User has a `List<Address>` with `FetchType=LAZY`.

If I add an `Address`object via user, within a `@Controller`, I get `failed to lazily initialize a collection of role - could not initialize proxy - no Session` exception.

But If I do this inside the service layer which is wrapped with `@Transactional`, operation works nicely.

I found out about hibernate proxies,...etc.

My question is, why `@Controller` cannot change an entity object which is retried from `@Service` layer. Because `@Controller` has no idea whether it is a hibernate proxy or anything else. To the `@Controller` it is just an object. So why I'm getting an error, if I change an entity object inside the @Controller. This is only happening to entity properties which are marked as `FetchType=LAZY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you choose a property to be lazily loaded, hibernate wraps those around a proxy having the session object in which the parent was fetched.

If you try to access the property after the session scope you will get this error.

Looks like your session is getting created and closed in service layer.

Implement  [OpenSessionInView](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html) Filter provided by spring, it will close the session after response being send.

Comment: But then there is a coupling between controller and dao?

Comment: No, by implementing OpenSessionInViewFilter you are actually removing  session management from your code thus separating your concerns which is good. Its a servlet filter which will manage hibernate session for you and you can write code without being worried about the hibernate session.